# Accessibility for servers with IPv6 and without IPv4

Tags: ipv6, shared-hosting, ipv4

I have a server that hosts many websites with Apache's vhosts function. Currently all sites have the same IP address as expected. I'm wondering if I can do something with IPv6 to give every website a unique IP address and stop IPv4 so that each website cant be seen as running on the same server.

And how will the internet service provider handle requests to a website that does not have IPv4.

Comment: If the users of the websites don't have IPv6, you are looking at something fairly complex. You should, at least by now, already be dual-stacking your web servers. You could then provide separate IPv6 addresses for those servers which have users who have IPv6, and you may be surprised at how large that number is.

Comment: The goal is to have every website with its own unique IP address; With the lost cost and availability of IPv6 I though  that would be a good place to start. Do you know of any kind of service or configuration that will enable met to have many IPv6 pointing to the same webserver and can handle IPv4 requests.

Id like the fact that all these websites are running on the same server to be hidden. If somebody were to tracert or nslookup they will not see the same IP from one website to another.

Comment: You can do that with IPv6 for IPv6 clients since IPv6 can have many addresses on a single interface, but having different IPv4 addresses requires IPv4 addresses. IPv4 and IPv6 are different protocols, and translation is problematic. If a client only has IPv4 how would you expect the client to be able to connect to separate IPv6 addresses, or any IPv6 at all, since the client computer doesn't understand IPv6. An IPv4 client doing a trace or nslookup will still end up with the single IPv4 address. That doesn't excuse the fact that you don't have IPv6 today.